# Rotate image layer maintaining center

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, catransform3d

Consider this image (size is 10x140; arrow is 10x70):

[image: Circle from 0 to 160° degrees]

The Red arrow is my problem, because I want it to rotate.

Now I'm using

```
CGFloat Angle = [Speed.text intValue] / 160.0;
_Arr.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(Angle * M_PI * 2, 0, 0, 1);
```

When `_Arr` rotates, it loses the center. As you see in the picture, the center is the plus ("+") sign, and the arrows in opaque are the problems.

I tried also to set center and anchor point, but I get the same results.
I made the arrow image double (double heigth, image half), same thing.

This is the interface builder:

[image: Interface builder]

What's could be the problem?

Is the `CATransform3DMakeRotation` the problem or the image? The anchor point? the degree formula? Both?

Comment: I suspect that's an image view. In this case, it's rotated around its `origin` - by default, that's in `(0, 0)`. Change it to reflect the actual center point and it'll be fine.

Comment: yes, it's an image view, but i change it? don't understand..

Comment: `imageView.origin = CGPointMake(5, 5);`

Comment: ah ok, but my imageview origin in not 0,0, is 155,105... i continue to not undertand...

Comment: experiment a bit with the values, eventually it'll be good.

Comment: no nothing. I don't able to make it work.

Comment: Y not change the '+' image view frame to be a little higher and then try and set the origin of the arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anchorPoint is the answer ("Shift the arrow center point to one of the end points of the image"). Check this tutorial http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/ios-tutorial-custom-speedometer-control/

Comment: very good, very good! It's what i need! +1 and +10! thanks a lot.